# Firebase Function - pass in function context

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Below is my firebase function:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.deleteUser = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '2GB'
  })
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {

  const userId = context.auth.uid;
  var promises = [];

  // DELETE DATA
  var paths = ['users/' + userId, 'messages/' + userId, 'chat/' + userId, 'like/' + userId];

  paths.forEach((path) => {
    promises.push(
      recursiveDelete(path).then(  () => {
          return 'success';
        }
      ).catch( (error) => {
        console.log('Error deleting user data: ', error);
      })
    );
  });

  // DELETE FILES
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  var image_paths = ["avatar/" + userId, "avatar2/" + userId, "avatar3/" + userId];
  image_paths.forEach((path) => {
    promises.push(
      bucket.file(path).delete().then(  () => {
            return 'success';
          }
         ).catch( (error) => {
          console.log('Error deleting user data: ', error);
        })
      );
    });

  // DELETE USER
  promises.push(
    admin.auth().deleteUser(userId)
    .then( () => {
      console.log('Successfully deleted user');
      return true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
    })
  );

  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    return true;
  }).catch(er => {
      console.error('...', er);
  });
});




function recursiveDelete(path, context) {
    return firebase_tools.firestore
    .delete(path, {
      project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
      recursive: true,
      yes: true,
      token: functions.config().fb.token
    })
    .then(() => {

      return {
        path: path
      }
    }).catch( (error) => {
      console.log('error: ', error);
      return error;
    });
  }
  // [END recursive_delete_function]
```

When calling this function, how can I pass in the `context.auth.id`?

Below is what i've tried:

```
async function deleteAccount(userId) {
  const deleteUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("deleteUser");
  deleteUser({ userId }).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data);
  });
}
```

But im getting the following error:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
```

I know the the `context.auth.id` is available server side but In this instance I need a way i can pass it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass user's UID in callable cloud function. The user must be logged in with Firebase authentication and Firebase SDKs will take care of the rest.

Can you try logging current user in `deleteAccount` function before calling cloud function just to ensure user is logged in? Also `context.auth.uid` is UID of user that is calling the function. If you want to access the userId that you are passing in the function, refactor the code as shown below.

---

The `deleteUser()` function would take only 1 parameter that's the data you want to pass in Cloud functions.

```
// not deleteUser({}, { userId })
deleteUser({ userId }).then((result) => {
  console.log(result.data);
});
```

When you are explicitly passing any data in Cloud function, that can be access from `data` and not `context`:

```
const { userId } = data;
```

Comment: Im still getting the same error `Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined`

Comment: I've updated my question with the new way you said to refactor the function

Comment: The reason I need to pass the UID in manually is this is a separate backend where I view data and can delete it, this is why no user is logged in.

Comment: @GurmukhSingh then you can access that UID that you are adding by `data.uid` and not from context.

Comment: this would mean I would need to modify my cloud function, was hoping to keep the function the same as its used my other applications

Comment: @GurmukhSingh you just need to change `context.auth.uid` to `data.userId`

Comment: thanks, just ended up edited my script to handle data.userid passed in... thanks